# Error deploying with heroku java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/servlet/jsp/tagext/TagLibraryValidator

Tags: java, heroku

I am trying to deploy my webapp in java with heroku, I implement this simple example:

```
package launch;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import org.apache.catalina.WebResourceRoot;
import org.apache.catalina.WebResourceSet;
import org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext;
import org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat;
import org.apache.catalina.webresources.DirResourceSet;
import org.apache.catalina.webresources.EmptyResourceSet;
import org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot;

public class Main {

private static File getRootFolder() {
    try {
        File root;
        String runningJarPath = Main.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath().replaceAll("\\\\", "/");
        int lastIndexOf = runningJarPath.lastIndexOf("/target/");
        if (lastIndexOf < 0) {
            root = new File("");
        } else {
            root = new File(runningJarPath.substring(0, lastIndexOf));
        }
        System.out.println("application resolved root folder: " + root.getAbsolutePath());
        return root;
    } catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    File root = getRootFolder();
    System.setProperty("org.apache.catalina.startup.EXIT_ON_INIT_FAILURE", "true");
    Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
    Path tempPath = Files.createTempDirectory("tomcat-base-dir");
    tomcat.setBaseDir(tempPath.toString());

    //The port that we should run on can be set into an environment variable
    //Look for that variable and default to 8080 if it isn't there.
    String webPort = System.getenv("PORT");
    if (webPort == null || webPort.isEmpty()) {
        webPort = "8080";
    }

    tomcat.setPort(Integer.valueOf(webPort));
    File webContentFolder = new File(root.getAbsolutePath(), "src/main/webapp/");
    if (!webContentFolder.exists()) {
        webContentFolder = Files.createTempDirectory("default-doc-base").toFile();
    }
    StandardContext ctx = (StandardContext) tomcat.addWebapp("", webContentFolder.getAbsolutePath());
    //Set execution independent of current thread context classloader (compatibility with exec:java mojo)
    ctx.setParentClassLoader(Main.class.getClassLoader());

    System.out.println("configuring app with basedir: " + webContentFolder.getAbsolutePath());

    // Declare an alternative location for your "WEB-INF/classes" dir
    // Servlet 3.0 annotation will work
    File additionWebInfClassesFolder = new File(root.getAbsolutePath(), "target/classes");
    WebResourceRoot resources = new StandardRoot(ctx);

    WebResourceSet resourceSet;
    if (additionWebInfClassesFolder.exists()) {
        resourceSet = new DirResourceSet(resources, "/WEB-INF/classes", additionWebInfClassesFolder.getAbsolutePath(), "/");
        System.out.println("loading WEB-INF resources from as '" + additionWebInfClassesFolder.getAbsolutePath() + "'");
    } else {
        resourceSet = new EmptyResourceSet(resources);
    }
    resources.addPreResources(resourceSet);
    ctx.setResources(resources);

    tomcat.start();
    tomcat.getServer().await();
}
```

}

and my jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<html>
<body>
<h2>Hola Mundo!</h2>

<a href="/hello">pincha aca</a>

<c:if test="${true}">
<h3>Hola</h3>
</c:if>

</body>
</html>
```

when I include the jstl in my project after doing the deploy it throws this exception:

[java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/servlet/jsp/tagext/TagLibraryValidator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kpdi.png)

my pom

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.heroku.sample</groupId>
<artifactId>embeddedTomcatSample</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>embeddedTomcatSample Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<properties>
    <tomcat.version>8.5.38</tomcat.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-jasper-el</artifactId>
        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>embeddedTomcatSample</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>appassembler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <assembleDirectory>target</assembleDirectory>
                <programs>
                    <program>
                        <mainClass>launch.Main</mainClass>
                        <name>webapp</name>
                    </program>
                </programs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>assemble</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

and my Procfile

```
web: sh target/bin/webapp
```

I tried everything but nothing worked. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

jakarta servlet is supported only in tomcat 10 version.

More so Heroku supports webapp-runner for tomcat 9.0.68.0, as of Oct 2022.

So the error.

Even if you deploy with 9.0.68.0, the code will fail for want of jakarta servlet.

Answer (score -1):

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/tld-summary.html

<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).